C++ thread based native lib / C# result axcess
I am trying to write a dynamic native library using c++ which will be used with c# applications.
The issue is am very confused about returning results from native lib. the thing is I need to create a thread inside the native lib. So the function inside the native livrary must create and return bool (or something else) the thread is created.
When the native thread is done, I need to pass the calculated data lets consider a single structure made with multiple integers to the native app.
so far I came up with 2 idea:
1- add a callback function parameter to the thread starting function and return true if thread started. and add another native function to try fetch the thread results, returns bool if thread finished, gets a struct reference parameter to fill it if thread is done. But still callback function is called inside the thread, so I need to code a lot to provent thread collisions from c# app.
2- returning an unique id(if thread not done -1, else 2) from native thread starting function, and one more for getting data like: bool(if thread done true, else false) GetThreadResult(int thread-id, void**(rawData(if thread not done nullptr else dataptr into void*)); how ever with a big thread based native lib, this will get complicated I think.
please forgive me if I am nonsense or unclear, not been too long starting nativeC++/C# concept.
I am sure there must be a more clever way to accoplisg this, I need some suggestion.
manys thanks for reading this long confused message, and any comments!

Either could work. Do you have a specific question? C++-CLI can make complex interfaces between C++ and .net simpler to implement

@AlanBirtles To be honest I have not read and tried, I will check it asap. Thanks.

Personally, I despise APIs where I have to poll for information (i.e. ask the API whether it has data for me, or whether I should ask again later). Of course, in general, I have some kind of event loop going on, so I generally send results as events -- however, I don't know C# or your application, so no idea whether that's an option for you at all. Callbacks are not that different if they are executed on the thread itself -- I still have to transfer the result to the thread that's actually going to use them, so there's some kind of event system going on regardless, it just might not be public.
